# Are there non-standard roads to research available for gifted students?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education

This is my first post here so I hope this is the right place to ask about this.

I am a 22 year old math fanatic in Sweden and have been put in the awkward position of having self-studied quite serious ''real math'' for about a year, and it has resulted from this that my university courses feel like a complete waste of time and that they actually damage my productivity, due to them being so easy, boring and not helping in moving me towards research I want to do. What's more the staff apparently doesn't want to talk to me at all and have consistently ignored my emails and seem to not be able to answer what I thought to be rather standard questions (eg. whether I could find some shortcuts for learning some Lie theory or homological algebra without having to read tons of exposition beforehand). They won't offer me any sort of deal and I feel completely alienated and invisible, I am not appreciated for having some special talent (particularly being really comfortable with abstract phenomena), but am instead treated as a burden. I am reading Bourbaki and Dieudonné's Éléments d'analyse and believe I am very well suited to Grothendieck-esque style, would like to work in the intersections of AG and (geometric) analysis.

Bearing this background in mind, my question is: Do I have any options for moving towards research other than continuing at my university or doing another standard undergraduate program? I have no interest in taking standardized courses which are not suited to my needs, and I mainly want to be somewhere where I can just talk math and get a view into what sort of research is done. My dream would obviously be something like the école normale supérieure but again they require that one has studied at least two years in such an undergraduate program. I would also love to have some sort of mentor, something like a PHD supervisor who I could just talk to. Do I have any real options or do I have to suffer through this for several years? Any advice on this is appreciated, I am quite desperate.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for mathematics.se.

Comment: I believe that you don't need 2 years of undergraduate to attend Ecole Normale Supérieure. At least if you are french, you can register to pass the exam (There are people who took the exam after the first year of preparation). I don't know how it is for students from abroad, but you might want to look into that.

Comment: If a course is easy for you, pass the exam, get a credit and move on to more advanced course. If your university does not offer advanced math course move to a different school. Study in your free time, there are plenty of books and online courses.

Answer (score 3):

In the real world, *saying* that you have a special talent is equivalent to stating, in math, that you *have* a result. You need a proof. Flawed as it may be, a standardized university curriculum is proof enough to show that you have mastered the basics of a field and are ready to dive into the more complex and interesting stuff.

If the courses are boring and simple, just give the exams: if you know the stuff they should be easy for you to give. Then, you can use the time to study ahead for the more advanced exams. Put in enough work and you may be able to graduate ahead of time.

If you are as smart and determined as you say, professors will notice and you will have no problem in entering a graduate program; sadly, professors receive countless emails about self-proclaimed geniuses and whatnot. Prove your worth by working hard also on the stuff you find boring; that's how you grow.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the point was of course neither to do polemics on the university system nor to claim that I am smart or whatever, I was simply trying to describe my situation. Additionally, my professor is of course teaching my current course so I do believe she should at least respond to my emails, and I obviously have never proclaimed myself a genius. If I have no alternatives, of course, I will do it this way, but as I was asking if there were other ways, I don't think this answers my question, maybe I should read that you think there are no such possibilities?

Comment: To put it crudely, it doesn't matter how good of a driver you are; even if the course is boring, you still need a driver's license to drive. Read books and work on cool stuff, then in the meantime give the exams you need to get that piece of paper :)

Answer (score 0):

*I am quite desperate.*

It may be reassuring to look at a concrete (and successful) example.

The [fields medalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal) [Artur Avila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artur_Avila) had a similar problem. While studying at research level at [IMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instituto_Nacional_de_Matem%C3%A1tica_Pura_e_Aplicada), in ortder to obatain his PhD degree, he had to study the basic at a university to obtain a bachelor degree first. According to him in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW3Osx71e-I&list=PLNW-oaKxRv0DatwMVnatKFIVngFCWpU8e&index=2) (in portuguese), some professors did not help him. For example, sometimes he was not allowed to take the exam because he did not attend the classes (he did not need classes because he knew the content). Funny fact: he took an exam in linear algebra one day before his thesis defense.

So, despite of being accepted to study at a research level without having finished the undergraduate level, he had to "suffer" to fulfill his bureaucratic obligations.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful motivation! Indeed I have heard of others in similar situations as well, Maxim Kontsevich says in his Heidelberg Laureate Forum interview that he would just spend his undergrad time going to research seminars and such, so I do think there are some good options. It is very nice to get an empathetic response and not to be judged as arrogant or self-aggrandizing, particularly as I have some psychological issues with unstable self-image, so thank you for engaging with the community in this positive way! :)

Comment: @LovaBolding You are welcome. And don't worry about the rude comments in this forum.